# Android MediaExtractor seek() accuracy with MP3 audio files

Tags: java, android, audio, mediaextractor

I am having trouble getting reasonable accuracy on seek() with Android `MediaExtractor`.  For some files, such as [this one](http://www.archive.org/download/emma_solo_librivox/emma_01_01_austen_64kb.mp3), I find significant inaccuracies (about 3 seconds in this case.)  I have the following flow:

1. call `setDataSource()` and `selectTrack()`
2. call `seekTo()`
3. call `play()`

In this case, it seeks to an incorrect position, but reports the correct position.  If I then seek to another position, it continues to be off by the same margin.  However, if I seek to 0, it corrects itself, and then will seek to the correct location in the file.

Is this simply a limitation / bug in MediaExtractor?  Does anyone have a fix / workaround to get more accuracy?  I would prefer not to start playback at position 0 before seeking, but I suppose that is one option.

Some other notes:

- Android MediaPlayer shows the same behavior.
- This happens whether I select `MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC` or `SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC`
- I see the same problem on KitKat and Lollipop, on the emulator and physical devices.
- A quick analysis of one failed file showed "Wrong number of MPEG data bytes specified in Xing header," but I got the same result for files that played fine.

Comment: It's a known limitation, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164072). You could maybe work around it bay including your own native library.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!  I had looked at that issue report, but I don't think it is about the same thing.  The poster is looking for *sample* accuracy instead of *microsecond* accuracy.  Millisecond accuracy is quite fine for me, but on a few recordings, when I seek before load, I get errors of more than a second.  Others work fine, as do those when I start playback from the beginning.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but ExoPlayer has its own MediaExtractor class for MP3s (and some other formats.)  If Google is abandoning the native MediaExtractor, maybe it is worth doing the same (and using their code) https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/extractor/mp3/Mp3Extractor.java

Comment: Possibly, but i've never worked with audio on Android, so I can't really help you there.

Comment: @Tad , how did you resolve this issue? I have a similar problem now and I asked this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742145/precise-seek-in-mp3-files-on-android

Comment: @vasiliy I wound up going back to MediaPlayer for other reasons, and just worked with the inaccuracies there.

Comment: @Tad, alright, thanks. Will try that too.